# Adding Anchor Tags to PDF

Tags: docusignapi

I created a Word doc with the text //SIGN_HERE// and wanted a signature tab to be added. I added this code here for a signature tab and when I sent the envelope, no signature tab was added when I went to add my signature in DocuSign. Any reason why? Also, when I received the document to sign via email, I was allowed to drag fields onto the document. How can I turn this off?

```
payload = json.dumps({
    'documents': [
        {
            'documentBase64': f'{encodedFile}',
            'documentId': '123',
            'fileExtension': 'docx',
            'name': 'test document'
        }
    ],
    'emailSubject': 'email subject',
    'recipients': {
        'signers': [
            {
                'email': 'example@example.com',
                'name': 'John Doe',
                'recipientId': '1',
                'routingOrder': '1'
            }
        ]
    },
    'tabs': {
        'signHereTabs': [
            {
                'accessibility': 'None',
                'anchorString': '//SIGN_HERE//',
                'anchorUnits': 'pixels',
                'anchorXOffest': '0',
                'anchorYOffest': '0',
                'name': 'Please Sign Here',
                'recipientId': '1',
                'tabLabel': 'signHere'
            }
        ]
    },
    'status': 'sent'
})
```

Comment: Hard to say what could be happening without more information. Please open a support case with DocuSign Developer Support here: https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US&Channels=7&_ga=2.190910569.211305195.1681777980-1200704038.1647235626&_gl=1*1w153sy*_ga*MTIwMDcwNDAzOC4xNjQ3MjM1NjI2*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTY4MTg4MDAxMy45OTguMS4xNjgxODgxNzk0LjYwLjAuMA..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what could be happening without more information. Please open a support case with DocuSign Developer Support [here](https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US&Channels=7&_ga=2.190910569.211305195.1681777980-1200704038.1647235626&_gl=1*t65a7f*_ga*MTIwMDcwNDAzOC4xNjQ3MjM1NjI2*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTY4MTg4MDAxMy45OTguMS4xNjgxODgxODAxLjUzLjAuMA..) and attach [API Request Logs](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) to the case

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are not at the envelope level.  They belong to particular signers.